# Ping between subnets

Tags: networking, server, iptables

I've created a Virtual network where there's a CLIENT---GATEWAY---SERVER

The client has IP `192.168.242.141`, the GATEWAY has two network interfaces with IPs `192.168.242.134` and `192.168.241.132` and the SERVER has two network interfaces as well `192.168.241.129`, `192.168.42.135`. The server is set for internet connection and has a NAT rule on iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.241.0/24 -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE
```

and the same rule is applied on the GATEWAY

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.242.0/24 -o ens34 -j MASQUERADE
```

both GATEWAY and SERVER has ip4 forward actived.

I can ping from subnet 242 to 241 but I can't ping the other way.

Is there a chance to do it or is it not possible? Do I need to create a new route on the GATEWAY from the backtraffic from 241 to 242?

Comment: `192.168.42.135` should be `192.168.242.135`

Comment: @Raffa nope; it's right because that subnet goes out to the NAT